# Issue With a Mysql Query Displaying A columns Data

Tags: mysql

I am trying to run this query from a drop down menu, the category and the destination data are working fine, just not the subcategory, it's probably an issue with my Html or Javasscript but i wanted to get the opinion of an expert with MYSQL if poss? I am quite new to PHP and MYSQL, but learning fast, Not sure my HTML will post here so i will just ask if someone can confirm that my query should work ok. Thanks guys.

```
$category=$_POST['Category'];
$subcategory=$_POST['Subcategory'];
$destination=$_POST['Destination'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM travel WHERE Category='$category' AND        Subcategory='$subcategory' AND Destination='$destination'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's a culprit in your case, but you have to escape data coming from a user before passing it to the query :

```
$category=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Category']); 
$subcategory=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Subcategory']); 
$destination=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Destination']);
....
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Alex07l, I will take a look and see what i can do with it.